# Does GlassFish Server need JDK or JRE in order to run Java EE applications?

Tags: glassfish, java

I want to Install GlassFish Server in a computer without a GUI. I would like to know if a JDK or a JRE is required in order to run Java Platform, Enterprise Edition (Java EE) applications?

Answer (score 2):

As GlassFish is an AS (Application Server) it looks like that the answer to the question is comparable to the accepted answer of [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726897/what-tomcat-requires-jdk-or-jre).

It depends on the WAR content. If the WAR contains JSPs, a JDK is required. Otherwise installing a JRE is sufficient.

However, the actual answer [according to this documentation](https://glassfish.java.net/getstarted.html) is that GlassFish requires a JDK, as Java EE makes use of some Java Standard Edition (SE) features.

```
Make sure JDK 7 is installed.

Java EE 7 requires JDK 7 as it make use of some of the latest Java SE 7 features (e.g. JMS 2 uses Java 7 auto-closeable interfaces).
To check if you have JDK 7 installed (full JDK, not just JRE), type javac -version in a shell/command box.
```